# Как определить, подключёно ли что-либо в разъём jack на звуковой карте?

Tags: железо, linux

Как определить, заняты ли разъёмы на звуковой карте или нет?

Сам момент подключения/отключения отлавливается через acpi_listener без проблем, и на это событие можно повесить скрипт, который отключает звук в колонках при подключении наушников во фронтальный разъём, а вот как проверить текущее состояние — не могу понять.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

согласно [вот этому ответу](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/58109/110559), информацию можно почерпнуть из файлов `/proc/asound/card*/codec#*`.

пример из этого ответа:

наушники подключены:

```
$ cat /proc/asound/card0/codec#0
[...]
Node 0x0d [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x400181: Stereo
  Control: name="Speaker Phantom Jack", index=0, device=0
  Pincap 0x00000014: OUT Detect
  Pin Default 0x90170110: [Fixed] Speaker at Int N/A
    Conn = Analog, Color = Unknown
    DefAssociation = 0x1, Sequence = 0x0
    Misc = NO_PRESENCE
  Pin-ctls: 0x00:
[...]
```

наушники отключены (сравните строки про `Pin-ctls`):

```
$ cat /proc/asound/card0/codec#0
[...]
Node 0x0d [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x400181: Stereo
  Control: name="Speaker Phantom Jack", index=0, device=0
  Pincap 0x00000014: OUT Detect
  Pin Default 0x90170110: [Fixed] Speaker at Int N/A
    Conn = Analog, Color = Unknown
    DefAssociation = 0x1, Sequence = 0x0
    Misc = NO_PRESENCE
  Pin-ctls: 0x40: OUT
[...]
```